# Data fetching from database using laravel and vuejs

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to fetching data from database using Laravel and Vue.js. 
Result I am getting is none. But firebug console shows the response. Please find the attached image. Please check my code and correct me. [image: Click Here]

**data.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Customers List')

@section('styles')
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Customers List</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="app">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Reference ID</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <?php
                            $i=1;
                            ?>
                            <tr v-for="message in messages">
                                <td> {{ $i }} </td>
                                <td> @{{ message.name }} </td>
                                <td> @{{ message.reference_id }} </td>
                                <td><a href="/customers/list/process/" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" role="button">Click Here</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php $i++; ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
    <script src="/js/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/customers.js"></script>
@endsection
```

**customers.js**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    ready: function() {
      this.fetchMessages();
    },

    methods: {
        fetchMessages: function() {
            this.$http.get('/customers/list/data', function(messages) {
                alert(messages);
                this.$set('messages', messages);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function showCustomersData()
    {
        $listCustomers             = Customer::select('id', 'name', 'reference_id')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->get();
        return response()->json(['messages' => $listCustomers]);
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/customers/list/data', [
        'as' => 'customerListData', 'uses' => 'CustomerController@showCustomersData'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited the controller part. Now I got result.
Replace `return response()->json(['messages' => $listCustomers])` with `return $listCustomers`.

```
public function showCustomersData()
    {
        $listCustomers             = Customer::select('id', 'name', 'reference_id')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->get();
        return $listCustomers;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to pre-initialise the messages variable in the Vue data object as per the warning message in your console. I think it depends on the version of VueJs you're using. Try:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        messages: []
    },

    ready: function() {
      this.fetchMessages();
    },

    methods: {
        fetchMessages: function() {
            this.$http.get('/customers/list/data', function(messages) {
                alert(messages);
                this.$set('messages', messages);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Still result is none. I am using vue js version 1.0.20

Comment: Do not forgot to add these on top of your page:<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/0.6.1/vue-resource.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using simulated ajax request to update grid data. Hopes to help you.

```js
var data = [{
  title: 'Test',
  description: 'This is a test.'
}, {
  title: '404Error',
  description: '404 Page not found.'
}];
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   messages: []
  },
  ready: function() {
   this.fetchMessages();
  },
  methods: {
   fetchMessages: function() {
     var self = this;
     // simulate the ajax request
     setTimeout(function(){
       self.messages = data;
     }, 1000);
   }
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
table th, table td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.20/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Index</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="message in messages">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{message.title}}</td>
    <td>{{message.description}}</td>
    <td><button>Click me</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</app>
```

P.S.
The first warning tells you to change your code, it prefers

```
// GET request
this.$http({url: '/someUrl', method: 'GET'}).then(function (response) {
    // success callback
}, function (response) {
    // error callback
});
```

The second warning tells you to pre-init the variable `messages` in `data`.
The last, sorry I don't know, haven't see it before.