# Loop through database table in Laravel Vue js Component

Tags: html, database, laravel, vue.js

This is an example of what I want to achieve in the vue component

```
<div v-for="emotion in emotions" class="cb-row">
    <h2>{{ emotion.em_name }}</h2>
</div>
```

I have created a function in the EmotionsController to return all data from the table

```
class EmotionsController extends Controller
{
    public function getEmotions() {

        $emotions = Emotions::all()->get();

        return $emotions;

    }
}
```

How do I then get this data into my vue component? It's being loaded into a form

Comment: you're missing input closure tag

Comment: Still having issues unfortunately. Do you know how to import data from the database table into the vue component?

Comment: return data in your Laravel Controller and in Vue you can receive it http get. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303720/data-fetching-from-database-using-laravel-and-vuejs

Comment: I'm fairly new to laravel and vue. I don't quite understand how to get the data into the component. Could I just use a simple route?

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer laravel documentation first. because it gave you everything what you want.
Here's the link of your question
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend#writing-vue-components